# Time difference in days in R

Tags: r, date

I'm having trouble getting the time difference between two dates. This is a sample of the data:

```
          Id       second_date     first_date
1      5402v        5-Dec-2014     9-May-1968
2     a3169y        7-Jul-2014    18-May-1936
3     a6230g        9-Oct-2015    30-Jun-1961
4     a6991u       25-Nov-2014     3-May-1982
5     a7481m        6-Apr-2014    29-Oct-1941
6     a8749y       28-Jan-2013    13-Jan-1977
```

I would like to subtract the two dates to get the number of days, but for some reason I would get `NA`. I've tried two approaches:

```
diff<-merge(Table2[!duplicated(Table2$Id),], Table4, by = "Id")
diff$second_date<-as.POSIXct(diff$second_date, format="%d/%m/%Y")
diff$first_date<-as.POSIXct(diff$first_date, format="%d/%m/%Y")
diff$diff<-diff$second_date - diff$first_date
```

and

```
diff$diff<- difftime(diff$second_date, diff$first_date, units = c("days"))
```

Comment: The `formats` are wrong. Your dates are `%e-%b-%Y`, not `%d/%m/%Y`, see https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html. Once both dates are proper `POSIXct` dates, the `difftime` should work if you just pass `"days"` as the `units` argument (without the `c()`)

Comment: In the future, it helps to run `dput(head(diff))` and paste the output in the question so people can quickly input the sample data into their R session.

Comment: Also, the `lubridate` package makes date parsing a lot easier. It has a set of functions, `dmy()` being the right one for this case, that expects date, month, year to be in a certain order (thus dmy) but will automatically figure out the exact format.